# Post request to Facebook Open-Graphs action?

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-opengraph

How come I can post correctly using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ with this url:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?object=http://guidepal.com/escape/30?access_token=xxx

where xxx is a valid access-token, even confirmed with

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

But when I try to use it directly on the browser url I get the json response:

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 2500
  }
}
```

I guessed this was because it was not a proper POST request. But I tried it using hurl.it and it did not work, tried using my code for an iPhone application and still the same response.
It's only when I use the explorer tool it actually works.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come I can post correctly using […] this url:
>
> `https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?object=http://guidepal.com/escape/30?access_token=xxx`

I bet you *can not* post using that *very* URL – because *name=value* pairs inside the query string are separated from each other with an `&`, *not* a second `?` as you are using in your URL.

With your URL you are giving just an `object` parameter with the value `http://guidepal.com/escape/30?access_token=xxx` – so no wonder that the API complains that you have not given an access_token, because effectively *you didn’t.*